# como fazer @Autowired em uma List<MeuComponente>?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Bom dia,

Tenho um componente que tem serviços injetados.
Esse componente é do escopo 'prototype' e fica rodando infinitamente. Preciso rodar X componentes (passado via argumento) desses e por isso gostaria de usar @Autowired List

Porém como fazer isso? Como trocar os 4 crawlers por uma List?

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Crawler implements Runnable {
    @Autowired private PaginaService service;
    @Autowired private StatusService statusService;
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // while loop infinito
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class CrawlerExecutor {
    @Autowired private Crawler crawler1;
    @Autowired private Crawler crawler2;
    @Autowired private Crawler crawler3;
    @Autowired private Crawler crawler4;

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor executor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner runner(TaskExecutor executor) {
        return new CommandLineRunner() {
            @Override
            public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
                executor.execute(crawler1);
                executor.execute(crawler2);
                executor.execute(crawler3);
                executor.execute(crawler4);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Valeu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A única solução que consegui pensar para este problema foi criar um Bean "qualificado" para a lista de Crawlers:

```
@Configuration
public class CrawlerList {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @Value("${numberOfCrawlers}")
    private int number;

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("crawlers")
    public List<Crawler> crawlers() {
        List<Crawler> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {          
            list.add((Crawler) context.getBean(Crawler.class));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

e alterar o CrawlerExecutor para injetar esse Bean "qualificado":

```
@Configuration
public class CrawlerExecutor {
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("crawlers")
    private List<Crawler> crawlers;

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor executor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner runner(TaskExecutor executor) {
        return new CommandLineRunner() {
            @Override
            public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
                for (Crawler c : crawlers) {
                    executor.execute(c);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```